# using phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: java, android, facebook, cordova

I am using phonegap facebook https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin plugin to build an facebook app. And following the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ . I did all the steps till step 2-personalize, and every thing worked fine, but now I am getting strange errors in my code, and tired to remove these errors. As I am new so I couldn't understand how to tackle these errors.Your help and guidance will be highly appreciated.Thanks
    Here is my Main Activity:
    package com.tcs.facebook;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int SPLASH = 0;
private static final int SELECTION = 1;
// private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;

private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS + 1;
private MenuItem settings;
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
    if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
        if (menu.size() == 0) {
            settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);        /* Error : settings    cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        menu.clear();
        settings = null;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);    /*Error : layout cannot be resolved or    is not a field*/

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);   /*Error : id cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment); /*Error : id cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment); /*Error : id cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment); /*Error : id cannot be resolved or is not a field*/

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    transaction.commit();
}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

private boolean isResumed = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
    };

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
    // resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

And here is my SelectionFragment.java
    package com.tcs.facebook;

```
import android.R;      /*Error : Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead*/
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "SelectionFragment"; 
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private TextView userNameView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, container, false);  /*Error :selection cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    // Check for an open session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // Get the user's data
        makeMeRequest(session);
        // Find the user's profile picture custom view
     profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)   /*Error : selection_profile_pic cannot be resolved or is not a field*/                    view.findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);
        // Find the user's name view
        userNameView = (TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);  /*Error :  selection_user_name cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    }
    return view;
}

private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    // Make an API call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response.
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    public void onCompleted1(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
            // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
            // view that in turn displays the profile
        // picture.
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
        // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // Handle errors, will do so later.
                    }
                }

        @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}

private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
        SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // Get the user's data.
        makeMeRequest(session);
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
            final Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
}
```

And here is SplashFragment.java :
    package com.tcs.facebook;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SplashFragment extends Fragment{

public class SkipLoginCallback {

    public void onSkipLoginPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);   /*Error : layout cannot be resolved or is not a field*/
    return view;
}

}
```

And also there is a red mark on R.java auto generated file.